# Are there any statistics or web services for n-grams of frequent English words?

Tags: english, computational-linguistics, nlp, software, n-grams

I found [this](http://www.chrisharrison.net/projects/trigramviz/) for six common subjects. But it doesn't contain the complete statistics about all common English words.

Comment: Do you want a list of the most common n-grams?  Or a way to look up the frequency of a particular n-gram?  (Google will let you do that.)  Or, like, "Give me the most frequent bigrams that begin with the word *watermelon*"?

Comment: Just most common n-grams.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [phrasesinenglish.org](http://phrasesinenglish.org/)'s "N-Grams Advanced" tool:

http://phrasesinenglish.org/explorengrams.html

It allows you to view 1- through 8-grams from the BNC (British National Corpus) in ascending or descending order, and provides a lots of granularity (filter by word pattern, POS etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Google has a nice project called [Google N-gram viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/). It contains around 1-million English words from all the books in Google Books Library. You can view the frequency graph of a word over the years and compare between frequency graph of different words.

The [data is also available for download](http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets) if you want to try some experiments over them. It consists upto 1-grams to 5-grams of data of Different forms of English (i.e. British, American) and some other Languages (Chinese, German, French ) too.

Comment: I found the data more easily on https://github.com/orgtre/google-books-ngram-frequency. Whatever people prefer :)